# Using vim/sed how do I replace the string "___COPYRIGHT___" with another string

Tags: vim, sed

I am having issues with sed/vim using the `s/replace this/with this` command.

Here are some screenshots to show the issue.

[image]

[image]

How do I match this string and replace it with what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to give a range. Otherwise, it only processes the current line.

```
:%s/.../.../
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple, thanks! Will accept once the time limit is up.